# measure the voltage of electronics component connected on breadboard using own software

Tags: breadboard, software

I wanted to ask something related to breadboard designing.
Is this possible that we can design own breadboard such that when it interact with software, then if you put the leads between the nodes of any electronic component then it can measure the voltage and show that voltage on software(just like when you put multimeter leads in between any component then it can measure the voltage of that component). I want to replace the multimeter with my software.
Please suggest me.

Comment: *I want to replace the multimeter with my software* And how would that work ? Software is just an algorithm, a multimeter is hardware. When you're hungry can you feed yourself using software ? Hint to what you need: Google "datalogger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace a multimeter with software, but you can replace it with an ADC and software.

Perhaps the 'softest' thing to use is an Arduino, as it connects to a PC easily, and has 6 analogue inputs for measuring voltage. Handy for controlling the breadboard as well.